# Is there a way to get all the intersection points of multiple curves with another curve?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, intersection

**Problem**
I need to get the intersection point of two curves several times. Given two dataframes as the following:

```
      name   flow  head
1       a     1     9
2       a     2     5
3       a     3     1
4       b     1     40
5       b     2     30
6       b     3     10
7       c     1     15
8       c     2     9
9       c     3     1
```

As you can see, "a" is a different curve from "b" and so on, but they all share the same x-axis. The second dataset is one simple curve:

```
      flow  system_head
1       1        1.2
2       2        5.6
3       3        9.5
4       4        17
```

**Sample resulting dataframe**
What I want to discover is a way to find the intersection between "head" and "system_head" for every different name:

```
      name   closest_flow_point  index_intersection_point
1       a           2                       2
2       b           3                       6
3       c           2                       8
```

I have been able to get the closest intersection value between two different columns with the following line of code:

```
idx = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(df["head"] - df2["system_head"]))).flatten()
```

but this doesn't work when I have multiple curves (e.g: curves "a", "b" and "c").

I have also been able to separate the "name" in different dataframes with a loop:

```
names = df["name"].unique()
for name in names:
    df_test = df.loc[df["name"] == name, :]
```

and while this does work in separating, I can't proceede from here.

It's also important to mention that there is no exact match for the columns ["head"] and ["system_head"] (which means that I can't use pd.where or pd.loc), and the dataframe has over a million rows.

To help visualize, [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcXVD.png), the blue lines would be the multiple curves and the red dots would be the intersection points, while the green line is the curve of the second df.

I also want to say that I would gladly sent the csv files to anyone that wants to try and solve the problem or needs further clarification

Comment: So `flow` is your x-axis and `head` is the y-axis? This looks like an interesting challenge that I'd love to work on. Please share your CSV file to Pastebin or Github

Comment: @CodeDifferent Yes, flow is the x-axis and head is the y-axis. Here [link](https://github.com/gustbztt/csv-files) are the .csv files so you can take a look. Thanks (in advance) for your help! I'm still trying to solve it (next I'll try and merge the dfs so I can get a reliable way to subtract the columns from one another).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do some exploratory analysis first:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("dataframeHm.csv", sep=";", decimal=",")

df_system = pd.read_csv("dataframeSystem.csv", usecols=[1,2])
df_system.columns = ["flow", "Hm"]

# Plot the curves
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
for name, sub_df in df.groupby("name"):
    ax.plot(sub_df["flow"], sub_df["Hm"], label=name)

ax.plot(df_system["flow"], df_system["Hm"], label="System", linestyle="--")
ax.set_xlabel("flow")
ax.set_ylabel("Hm")
ax.legend()
```

[image]

We see that only `KSB 32-160 144` intersects the system curve. How we are going to identify the intersection points require some finesse.

---

## 1

If we assume that the system curve has a y-value whenever an individual curve has a y-value, we can simply merge them on the x-axis (`flow`):

```py
tmp = (
    pd.merge(df, df_system, on="flow", suffixes=("", "_system"))
    .assign(is_equal=lambda x: np.abs(x["Hm"] - x["Hm_system"]) < 0.01) # find a threshold that suits your requirements
)
```

This is enough to give us some info about the intersection points:

```
tmp[tmp["is_equal"]]

                  name      flow        Hm  Hm_system  is_equal
18570  KSB  32-160 144  0.004061  35.52770  35.522806      True
18572  KSB  32-160 144  0.004062  35.52644  35.527495      True
18574  KSB  32-160 144  0.004063  35.52518  35.532185      True
```

But instead of a single point, the algorithm found 3 consecutive points that intersect the system curve! We can refine this a little bit by implementing a rule: if consecutive points intersect the system curve, we will take the mean `flow` of those points:

```py
intersects = {}
for name, sub_df in tmp.groupby("name"):
    is_equal = sub_df["is_equal"]
    if is_equal.sum() == 0:
        continue

    sub_df["island"] = is_equal.ne(is_equal.shift()).cumsum()
    intersects[name] = sub_df[is_equal].groupby("island")["flow"].mean().to_list()

# intersects: {'KSB  32-160 144': [0.004062]}
# 0.004062 is the `flow` value of the intersection point
```

---

## 2

A more advanced scenario is that the system curve may not have some `flow` values present in the individual curve. If you refer back to the chart, you can see that the system curve looks pretty much like a quadratic curve, so let's try some curve fitting:

```py
poly, residuals, *_ = np.polyfit(df_system["flow"], df_system["Hm"], deg=2, full=True)

# poly: array([5.77047893e+05, 1.54957651e+00, 2.60000005e+01])
# residuals: array([9.45696098e-13])
```

This is an extremely good fit as the residuals are near 0. So we can use `poly` to interpolate the system curve value at any point:

```py
tmp = (
    df.assign(Hm_system=np.polyval(poly, df["flow"]))
    .assign(is_equal=lambda x: np.abs(x["Hm"] - x["Hm_system"]) < 0.01)
)
```

And you can apply the same algorithm above to identify the intersection points.

Comment: this worked like a charm! I ended up using the first solution since I am the one generating the 'flow' vector and its step, but it's nice to learn the second solution. The system curve is actually generated as a quadratic curve, hence it works greatly.